# splitting words from a text box using in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m new To ASP.net i want to send mail to multiple people by using one textbox and every email address is separated by `,`. Now I want to send mail to multiple people. My code is

```
public static void SendEmail(string txtTo, string txtSubject, string txtBody, string txtFrom)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.valuesoft.org", 26);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@----.org", "@123");
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom);
            mailMsg.To.Add(txtTo);
            mailMsg.Subject = txtSubject;
            mailMsg.Body = txtBody;
            mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(mailMsg);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Now, This is confusing "using one textbox and every textbox is separaterd by (,)". Could you please elaborate what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Can you send the format/ pattern of the string in textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for how to parse a comma seperated list:

```
string[] recipients = txtTo.Split(',');
foreach (string recipient in recipients)
{
     mailMsg.To.Add(recipient );
}
```